# Multiple displays and resolution

Tags: display, monitors, scaling

I downloaded and tried Odin but could not set resolution for my laptop + external monitor correctly.
Here's the deal:

- Laptop display is 4K
- External monitor is FHD

No matter what I tried, I got either:

- external monitor would show grotesquely huge widgets and fonts
- laptop monitor would show miniscule widgets and fonts

I was unable to individually set (or scale) the displays to make them look similar.

Extremely sorry for saying this but I use other desktop environments for as long as I an remember and this has not been an issue, even with 2 or 3 external monitors, each with different screen resolutions.

Why is this so hard?

Yes, I can use xrandr (and even arandr) but should I need to for a desktop that is otherwise so awesome? Is the issue in some upstream library?

FWIW, KDE/Plasma has never had issues scaling displays individually (Wayland) or setting resolutions individually on X11/Xorg.

Answer (score 0):

I have FHD laptop and 2k external monitor, all works fine. Both monitors work in loDPI mode. In your case laptop monitor must be set hiDPI and external to loDPI. It is possible to do in Default settings ->Display settings.

So you didn't specify OS version, I'm referring to Hera and up.

Lastly eOS does not support fractional scaling. Devs themselves recommended to use xrandr for this.

Comment: Can you provide details on how you set LoDPI and HiDPI individually for each display? That does not appear to be possible on my system running eOS 6.